# How to subset an array using another one with boolean values using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I couldn't find that in the documentation, is there a built in simple way to subset an array using a boolean array for filtering? In lodash or es6

I used to use this feature in `R` a lot and it seemed to be quite useful. Lately I faced several use cases when I could use something like that but couldn't find out if it is supported out of the box.

something like

```js
subset([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [true, false, false, false, true]) // => [1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const filter = [true, false, false, false, true];

const result = arr.filter((r, i) => filter[i]);
console.log(result);
```

You can use built in `filter` array function. It has a signature which accepts an index also you can use it to filter your array as below :

Answer (score 2):

A quick way of doing this would be something like

```
const f = (as, bs) => as.filter((_, i) => bs[i])
f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [true, false, false, false, true])  // => [1, 5]
```

This assumes that the two arrays have the same length, which might or might not be what you want.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they have the same length. Since `undefined` is a falsy value. It will only include the length of the filter array.

Comment: What if the default assumption was to include the value instead? That wouldn't work. I'm just saying that calling this function with two arrays of different length doesn't make much sense if you don't specify the exact semantics

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
zip=rows=>rows[0].map((_,c)=>rows.map(row=>row[c]))
zip([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [true, false, false, false, true]]).filter(e => e[1])
// [ [ 1, true ], [ 5, true ] ]
```